# C++ Multiplication of two matrices

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl

Hello guys I don't see the logic in this multiplication of [4x4]matrices:

```
void matrix::multiplicate( GLdouble nm[ 16 ] )
{
    char x, a, b;
    GLdouble tm[ 16 ];

    for( x=0 ; x<16 ; x++ )
    {
        a = x % 4;  
        b = (x / 4) * 4;

        tm[ x ] = nm[ a    ] * mx[ b   ] +
              nm[ a+4  ] * mx[ b+1 ] +              
              nm[ a+8  ] * mx[ b+2 ] +
              nm[ a+12 ] * mx[ b+3 ];
    }

    for( x=0 ; x<16 ; x++ ) 
        mx[ x ] = tm[ x ];
 }
```

When the for-loop(x = 0) makes his first round `a` and `b` are 0. That's logical -> First row * First column

```
tm[ 0 ] =     nm[ 0  ] * mx[ 0 ] +
              nm[ 4  ] * mx[ 1 ] +              
              nm[ 8  ] * mx[ 2 ] +
              nm[ 12 ] * mx[ 3 ];
```

But now `x = 1`: Second row * First column

```
tm[ 1 ] =     nm[  1 ] * mx[ 1 ] +
              nm[  5 ] * mx[ 2 ] +              
              nm[  9 ] * mx[ 3 ] +
              nm[ 13 ] * mx[ 4 ];
```

`mx[4]` is in the Second column .... it has something to do with `b` but I don't get it.

Comment: Best use a debugger and go through the program line by line and watch the values changing, this should give you a conception of what's actually going on.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to use a nested loop, recalculating the index each time?

Comment: `x == 1` is cell `[0, 1]`: first row, second column.

Comment: And why are you using `char` for the indices.  `int` would be far more natural.

Comment: @JamesKanze Or `size_t`, which would be even more _natural_ IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `size_t` is an unsigned integral type, and so should be avoided for anything arithmetic.  The "natural" type (at least according to the standard, and the authors of the language) is `int`.  If you risk having to deal with really big arrays, you might use `ptrdiff_t`, but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `b` is an integer, so `b/4` is integer division, and when `x=1`, `b/4` is `0`, so `b=0`

So `(x/4)*4` makes `b` go up by 4s. `b` will be 0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,8,8,8,8...

Comment: Which is, of course, what he wants (although `b = x - a` would work equally well, and probably be a bit faster).